# want to get a list of all the ids of something that acts_as_tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-tree

I have a Category that can have Headers which are acts_as_tree. The structue could this be like:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :headers
end

class Header < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  acts_as_tree :order => :position
end

Category:
  Header
  Header
    Header
      Header
      Header
  Header
```

I'd like to extract all of the ids of the Headers for a Category.

Is there something that's done for me automatically? Or is there a simple way to traverse?

thx in advance

Comment: `Category` and `Header` are two different models with `has_many/belongs_to` relationship?

Comment: edited the code to reflect the relationships

Answer (score 0):

First of all retrieve a category you need like:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
```

then

```
ids = @category.headers.map(&:id)
```

This line will return the array of headers' ids for a special category

Comment: thx, Sergey. I tried this but the problem is that it doesn't descend the heirarchy for the headers that aren't top level.

Comment: The best thing you acn do is to use `ancestry` gem instead becaue `acts_as_tree` is very limited in functionality. Or you can write a monkey-patch like setting `category_id` for a child header according to its parent`s `category_id` value somewhere in `after_create` callback